# Show MDIChild Form from another MDIChild Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, mdichild, mdiparent

Let’s I have **MDIParentForm (Home)**, **Child Form (Form1, Form2)**, **Home** has one **Menu (Add)** and **Form1** has **button (btnOk)**

'''''Here is C# Code''''''

```
 public partial class Home : DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm
{
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void  CreateForm(Form frm)
    {
        frm.MdiParent = this;
        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        frm.Show();
    }
    private void btnAddForm_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        CreateForm(frm);
    }
}
//Up to this 1st level my code works fine.
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//From Here I am not able show the Form2.
        Home MDIParentForm = new Home();
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        MDIParentForm.CreateForm(childForm);
    }
}
```

Action: On the click of **Add** Menu I used to open **Form1** (It works fine) and on the click of **btnOk** I want to open **Form2** (which is another MDIChild form).

Let me know how we can accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is you create yet another instance of your MDI parent and you set the `Form2` as a child of this newly created MDI parent. This is clearly wrong, you want both to be children of the very same parent.

Either do this directly:

```
private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    // both have the same MDI parent
    frm.MDIParent = this.MDIParent;
    frm.Show();
}
```

or, if you insist on reusing your `CreateForm`

```
private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    ((Home)this.MDIParent).CreateForm( frm );
}
```

Both approaches depend on `this.MDIParent` set in form1 and make sure the same instance is used for newly created form2.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor Zychla, I got solution as you have shown in 2nd Demo. But I have 2nd case where From1 has been displayed in normal window(Not MdiChild) and from the normal window I am adding the new MdiChild. Here is my code..

Comment: public partial class Home : DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm
{
    private void btnAddForm_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        //CreateForm((frm));
         frm.Show();
    }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
    ((Home)this.MDIParent).CreateForm( frm );//Here I get Null reference exception .
    }
}

Comment: Create a new question for this case and let me know by adding a comment here.